# How to search text surrounded by double-quotes with RegEx?

Tags: regex

I have a string with some HTML code in, for example:

```
This is <strong id="c1-id-8">some</strong> <em id="c1-id-9">text</em>
```

I need to strip out the `id` attribute from every HTML tag, but I have zero experience with regular expressions, so I searched here and there from the internet and I wrote this pattern: `[\s]+id=\".*\"`

Unfortunately it's not working as I would expect. Infact, I was hoping that the regular expression would catch the `id="` followed by any character repeated for any number of times and terminated with the **nearest** double quote; Practically in this example I was expecting to catch `id="c1-id-8"` and `id="c1-id-9"`.
But instead the pattern returned me the substring `id="c1-id-8">some</strong> <em id="c1-id-9"`, it finds the first occurrence of `id="` and the last occurrence of a double quote character.

Could you tell me what is wrong in my pattern and how to fix it, please?
Thank you very much

Comment: For the ∞​th time, **use a parser.** HTML is not a regular language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quantifier `.*` in your regex is **greedy** (meaning it matches as much as it can). In order to match the minimum required you could use something like `/\s+id=\"[^\"]*\"/`. The brackets `[]` indicate a character class. So it will match **everything inside of the brackets**. The carat `[^]` at the beginning of your character class is a negation, meaning it will match **everything *except* what is specified in the brackets**.

An alternative would be to tell the `.*` quantifier to be **lazy** by changing it to `.*?` which will match as little as it can.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand how it works: (1) it starts by searching any amount of space + id=" (2) it searches any characther until a double quote character is found (3) it searches a double quote char.

Comment: Correct. And kudos for going out and researching your problem before posting it here, that's always helpful

Comment: @ridgerunner Excellent clarifications/corrections. I've edited my answer to hopefully be more accurate

Answer (score 4):

In `.*` the asterisk is a greedy quantifier and matches as many characters as it can, so it only stops at the last `"` it finds.

You can either use `".*?"` to make it lazy, or (better IMO), use `"[^"]*"` to make the match explicit:

```
"      # match a quote
[^"]*  # match any number of characters except quotes
"      # match a quote
```

You might still need to escape the quotes if you're building the regex from a string; otherwise that's not necessary since quotes are no special characters in a regex.

Answer (score 1):

A parser is the best solution in the general case, but they to take time to write. There are cases where writing one would take more time than the parser would save; perhaps this is such a time.

What you want is a either a non-greedy match or a more precise match. /[\s]+id=\".*?\"/ will do the trick, but [\s]+id=\"[^"]*\" will be faster.

Note that a full regex that takes into account the possibility of escaped quotes characters, allows single quotes instead of double quotes, and allows for the absence of quotes entirely would be much more complex. You would really want a parser at that point.

Answer (score 1):

example with grep: (but the point is the expression)

```
kent$  echo 'This is <strong id="c1-id-8">some</strong> <em id="c1-id-9">text</em>'|grep -oP '(?<= id=")[^"]*(?=">)'
c1-id-8
c1-id-9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your `id` is always 7 characters, you could do this.

```
/\sid=".{7}"/g
```

So..

```
var a = 'This is <strong id="c1-id-8">some</strong> <em id="c1-id-9">text</em>';

var b = a.replace(/\sid=".{7}"/g, '');

document.write(b);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/XPMze/

Check the inspector to see the `id`s removed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately the ID string could be of any length and I have no control on it :-(

Comment: Whoever downvoted this.  I don't mind the downvote, but could you tell me why?